# Using 'generify' to mean 'to make generic'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, word-usage

Can one use the term *generify* to mean 'to make generic'? E.g. a software programmer being told: 'generify this segment of code'.

If not, what may be a single word replacement of this phrase?

Answer (score 29):

**Genericise / genericize** is the version I most frequently hear. Out of interest, I ran an ngram test, with [*generify*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=generify&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) not getting a single hit. [*Genericize*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=genericize&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), however, has risen in usage from the '80s.

Answer (score 11):

*Generify* is certainly the right word to use in the context of Java generics.

This is from the Java Language Specification preface:

> Joe Darcy and Ken Russell implemented much of the specific support for reflection of generics. Neal Gafter, Josh Bloch and Mark Reinhold did a huge amount of work **generifying** the JDK libraries.

In other fields, *genericise / genericize* would be better recognised, as answered by Mr. Disappointment.

Answer (score 6):

The dictionary doesn't display a result, but does come up with "generification", which I assume is where "generify" comes from.
There's the alternatives of "generalize" or "abstract".

Comment: Generalize is the term I use when adjusting code to be less specialized and cover additional use cases

Answer (score 1):

I think so. It gets used all the time in my <strike>workspace</strike> workplace.

.:. it is fine to used as words evolve over time.

Comment: Until you get to generifyizication - then you should stop.

Comment: Agreed. We must stopifyizicate all generifyizication!

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, the usual word used for this context is `generalize`.