# Single word for "Make a Template"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Single word for "Making a Mold" or some such will work too.  I can't think of it and the Google is ironically overtaken by Microsoft Powerpoint links when I try to search for an answer there.

Hoping for something better than "templetize".

Context: I want to name a machine that does the reverse of what a template does.  I.e., instead of using a template to make an instance of an object, it takes an object, removes the specific properties that make the object a specific instance, and basically leaves you with a template you could use to create objects with.

Comment: *Template* as a verb might serve, but I'd want more of an understanding of just how you were planning to use it before I'd be confident in that as an answer.

Comment: SWR would be better served to provide use in context. Please check the tag wiki for examples of how to ask.

Comment: Sad to say, in the computer software realm folks are fond of "templatize".

Comment: @JonHanna, perhaps _Template_ is the answer, though it is unfortunate it is indistinguishable from the noun.  Would there be a name for the person that _templates_?

Comment: Sounds like your process is **abstracting** the content. In other words, deriving metadata from data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Formalize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/formalize)" implies taking an existing process and detailing it in a more permanent form (one of which could be a template).

Going by your context, however, I'd say "[Abstract](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abstract)" is a closer verb to what you're looking for, as it implies removing specifics and formulating a higher-order view.

Comment: I like abstract.

Answer (score 2):

"Template" as a verb is likely the most correct usage. Having derived its etymology from "plate" (Fr.), we can associate it to a chef's arrangement of a meal on a dish for presentation to a guest, which is widely (though perhaps somewhat colloquially) referred to as "plating".

Similarly, in software engineering, we can "template" a fragment of code or markup to be used over and over again and populated with variable values in different contexts. This metaphor is a close match.

That said, "templetize" or "templatize" both imply the genericizing or fabrication of an existing design in order to make it into a usable template, and may be more appropriate for your context.

Comment: Might have to go with this one unless someone comes up with something better (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that *template* as a verb may best serve your purpose. However, another word to consider is ***generalize***:

```
2 a :  to derive or induce (a general conception or principle) from particulars
  b :  to draw a general conclusion from
```

<sup>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generalize))</sup>

But, you may also wish to consider [other forms of "to make generic"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28889/87426).